# How to switch many (15) low power (40W) lightbulbs from a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, switches, mains

The power rating on the bulb is the amount of power the PSU has to deliver in order for the bulb to light up the brightest right? Hence if it's a 40w bulb I need 40watts of power for it to light up properly right?

If so then my dilema is I have 15 or so light bulbs which need to be switched on and off invididually. The only way I can think of is using a relay but that means 15 relays!! It's turn on and off by a microcontroller which switches the relay on and off. I need to use bulbs because the person am doing it for insists on bulbs

Comment: Sorry, but I fail to see any correspondence between the title and the actual question in the body. Could you consider rewriting the title to be more precise?

Comment: Ok, I took a shoot at the title myself. Feel free to correct me if you wish.

Comment: Hmm.. what about this? http://sparkbangbuzz.com/mag-amp/mag-amp.htm

Comment: @Earlz, It is nice but unfortunately neither cheap nor small.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be asking two different questions here...

**Do I need 40w of power to light up a 40w bulb?**

Answer: yes you do, if it's less then the bulb will be dim or not light at all.

**How do I switch 15 bulbs independently using a microcontroller?**

Answer: yes, you can either use relays as a nice simple solution. But if you need to switch them quickly, or many times over a long period of time then you should use solid state relays or triacs.

Answer (score 5):

Are these large DC (eg automotive) bulbs, or small mains bulbs?

If you're fuzzy on what a Watt means, you're not ready to be tackling high voltage circuits.

Answer (score 4):

You can use mechanical or solid-state relays (SSR).

A mechanical relay offers the advantage that when off there's a complete separation between the bulb and the mains. You'll need a transistor to drive the relay.

You can buy SSRs which you can drive directly from your microcontroller, but they're not cheap. No problem, because you can create the same functionality cheap with just a few components.
You start with an opto-triac like the [MOC3041](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/MO/MOC3041-M.pdf) (that's for 230V applications, use MOC3031 for 115V). It's like an ordinary opto-coupler but with a triac as the switch instead of a transistor (a triac can switch AC, which a transitor can't). If you don't use this opto-triac your whole circuit will be connected to the mains!
The MOC3041 has the additional feature of switching on the zero-crossing of the mains' sine. Incandescent bulbs tend to fail when being switched on, and when the mains voltage is near a maximum. Zero-crossing switching prolongs the bulb's life.
The MOC3041 can't drive large currents directly, therefore we use it to drive a power triac.
[image: MOC3041 application circuit]

Answer (score 3):

You can use either relays or triacs (with optoisolation). There are no easier or cheaper ways around this.

Answer (score 3):

What is the objection to relays?

If they are DC bulbs you can use 15 transistors. Or you could build a 3x5 matrix and switch them that way with just 8 transistors and a lot more complexity...

Comment: Incandescent lamps don't multiplex well: either the current pulses are too low which results in lamps lighting only faintly, or the light is OK but then the higher current pulses will significantly reduce the bulb's life.